# WooCommerce: How to show product addon price?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can can I display product addon price along with option value? I'm using YITH product addon plugin.
Product page - https://pizza-end.com/product/margherita/
How I want addon price to be displayed - https://demo.chethemes.com/pizzaro/product/hawaii-vegetarian-pizza-3/

Comment: This is most probably because of how your current theme has template to show them. You must check if there is any kind of filter or something that is added in your theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to update that I have found the bug, in customized theme source code for this plugin the name of the output file was misspelled. Resolved.